# Part of view with storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I'm working on a Google Maps-app, and I want a certain behavior. When tapping a marker I want the "Detail View", displayed below to popup. If swiping that detail view up I want it to cover the whole screen and make "MORE DETAIL" appear. If swiping down, it will close it.

[image: My ideal behavior]

I just can't figure out how to implement this behavior. Container View? Just a regular UIView wit gesture recognizer? Modal segue?

I'm not asking for code, just some words to get me on the right track.

Edit: For anyone else looking for this kind of behavior, every answer below is perfectly fine. I went with the container view, since the detail view is doing some network requests and `UITableView` work.

Comment: You could make put the detail and more detail view on a scrollView and set the default content offset so that only the detailView is showing, disable scrolling on the scrollView, add the gesture recognizer, and then after the gesture is recognized re-enable scrolling and scroll the detail view up to the top.

Comment: Hi @MatthewLawrenceBailey, I tried your approach, but I have to admit I'm not experienced with UIScrollViews. I managed to calculate the correct offset, but when I start to scroll it, everything inside to scroll view jumps up half the screen, instead of following my finger. Would you know what I did wrong?

Comment: scroll views have a subview called contentView, which must be bigger than the scrollView in order for it to scroll, what happens is the contentView isn't extending past the bottom of the screen enough for it to hold it down, here is a link to apple docs on scrollViews content size https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with Pan gesture and I would say by having Parent ViewController (Container) and Child ViewController instead UIView. Let me know if you would need more help :)

Comment: I managed to do this with UIView. Why would you prefer Container? I'd love to know more!

Comment: I am using kind of same functionality in one app now. I prefer container view controller approach because in that way you de couple your logic of main view (here its Map) and pull up view. And its more reusable :)

Comment: I tried your way, and it works fine. However, now I'm animating the containers' vertical spacing to "Top lay out guide" constraint to make the view snap. Is this approach decent or terrible? Example: When only the top detail view is showing, I'm setting the constraint to screen size - topView.frame.height.

Comment: I think if possible do it with constraints instead taking frame? But I don't think its terrible :D

Comment: I managed to do it with constraints, so it looks good on my iPhone and in the iPad Simulator. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Glad to hear that you are happy with the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

go with UIView and `UIGestureRecognizer`, it would be faster and simpler. Modal segue does not cover the whole page as you want, and container view is too much work to put on just a simple thing